# where could I find deployed SSIS package?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

After I deploy a .dtsx SSIS package is there any query or C# code i could run to get it's bath on the drive or could I retrieve the deployed .dtsx file.

Comment: Where did you deploy the package in File System or Sql server ?

Comment: yes in sql server,so it's stored in the msdb database but how could I retrieve it or open it ?

Comment: Connect to `Integration Services` in the `object explorer` inside SSMS .Enter the credentials to `log in`.Expand `Stored Packages` then `MSDB` and locate the package in this folder

Comment: Right click on the package and click `execute`

Comment: thank you Praveen but i don't want to execute it I want to get the inner code of the package .. i want a suitable way to get the inner data of the package as i'm developing a function to read the connection strings from the packages. I mean in the .DTSX file there are the connection strings as example could i got this information ?

Comment: r u trying to execute the ssis package using C# ? Do u want pass paramaters thru code ? Kindly be clear in your inputs so that we can help u out

Comment: I dont want to execute it using C#. i want to get the detailed information about the packages as it was in the .dtsx file because i want to get the connection strings related to the package

you could understand me more if you see this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546019/how-to-get-sql-jobstep-connection-strings

i'm so sorry again if I couldn't clear my requirements but it's very urgent for me and i try to get the closest answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the package is stored in `MSDB` so `Right Click` on the SSIS package placed in SQL Server and then click `Run Package` .
You will get a dialogue box

[image]

Click on the `Connection Managers` tab and then change the connetion strings for individual connection.

Else

if SSIS package is created using `xml config file` then click the `configuration tab` and open the config file to know the details of package

Update 1:-

1. Assigning values to SSIS package variables

Add this namespace  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;`

```
Application app = new Application();
Package package = null;
package = app.LoadPackage(deployed ssis package path,null) //Load DTSX path
//Access the SSIS variables
pkg.Connections["sConn"].ConnectionString = strSourceConn;
pkg.Connection["dConn"].ConnectionString = strDestConn;
```

2.Reading XML

Underlying code for every dtsx package is `xml` .So you can load the XML using C# and then iterate through each node and find the information .

3.Getting information from dtsx.config file .

As i said above the ssis package may have a xml config file which stores all the information.This xml file is much easier to read in C# then reading the entire DTSX package mentioned in `point 2`

4.If package configuration is stored in sql server then use the below code .The code is taken from [Collecting Information of SSIS package](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/10/18/collecting-information-about-your-ssis-packages-ssis-nugget.aspx)

```
    SELECT    Props.Prop.query('.') as PropXml,
    Props.Prop.value('declare namespace p1="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";
    string(./@p1:Name)','nvarchar(max)')  as PropName,
    Props.Prop.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as PropValue
    FROM    (
    SELECT    CAST(pkgblob.BulkColumn AS XML) pkgXML
    FROM    OPENROWSET(bulk 'C:\tmp\MyPkg.dtsx',single_blob) AS pkgblob
    ) t
    CROSS    APPLY pkgXML.nodes('declare namespace DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";
                    /DTS:Executable/DTS:Property') Props(Prop)
```

Conclusion :-

If the SSIS package is created using config file . Locate where it is stored . 
If it is stored in `XML configuration type` then load that XML file in C# and search for the nodes . If the ssis data is stored in `sql server` then run the above sql and get all the information . The sql query returns you the package details in xml type which you can read in C# and get the desired information

Update 2:-

If SSIS package is deployed in sql server then the below code will help you retrieve the package details using C#

```
public class SSISDetails
{
    public string PackageData { get; set; }
    public string PackageName { get; set; }
}

  string storedProc = string.Empty;
        List<SSISDetails> _pkgcol = new List<SSISDetails>();
        string connectionString = "server=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SSISDetails", conn)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        })
        {

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read ())
                {
                    _pkgcol.Add(new SSISDetails() 
                    {
                       //Please don't write the code like the one below accessing 
                       //columns  using index .
                        PackageName =reader[2].ToString (),
                        PackageData =reader[10].ToString ()
                    });

                }

            conn.Close();
        }

        foreach (var item in _pkgcol.Where (a=>a.PackageName =="YourPackageName") )
        {
            //read the item.PackageData and using Linq to xml retrieve the nodes which
            //you want
        }
```

The Stored Proc which retrives the information is :-
The below sql code gives the `package name` ,`path`,`description` and `package data` in `xml` format

```
 Create Procedure SSISDetails
 as 
 begin
 with ChildFolders
 as
 (
   select PARENT.parentfolderid, PARENT.folderid, PARENT.foldername,
    cast('' as sysname) as RootFolder,
    cast(PARENT.foldername as varchar(max)) as FullPath,
    0 as Lvl
   from msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders PARENT
   where PARENT.parentfolderid is null
   UNION ALL
   select CHILD.parentfolderid, CHILD.folderid, CHILD.foldername,
   case ChildFolders.Lvl
        when 0 then CHILD.foldername
        else ChildFolders.RootFolder
    end as RootFolder,
    cast(ChildFolders.FullPath + '/' + CHILD.foldername as varchar(max))
        as FullPath,
    ChildFolders.Lvl + 1 as Lvl
   from msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders CHILD
   inner join ChildFolders on ChildFolders.folderid = CHILD.parentfolderid
   )
   select F.RootFolder, F.FullPath, P.name as PackageName,
   P.description as PackageDescription, P.packageformat, P.packagetype,
   P.vermajor, P.verminor, P.verbuild, P.vercomments,
   cast(cast(P.packagedata as varbinary(max)) as xml) as PackageData
   from ChildFolders F
   inner join msdb.dbo.sysssispackages P on P.folderid = F.folderid
   order by F.FullPath asc, P.name asc;

end
```

Comment: yes you are right I did that and works for me and that's what i exactly what I need to get by code .. so is there anyway to get those connection using C# code not by wizard ?

Comment: i really appreciate your efforts helping me .. thank you so much but really this is not working for me as in those 2 cases I have to know the bath for the package with is not feasible while the package is deployed .. the 1st case you told me
package = app.LoadPackage(deployed ssis package path,null)
in the other 
 FROM    OPENROWSET(bulk 'C:\tmp\MyPkg.dtsx',single_blob) AS pkgblob
in both cases i dont have .DTSX file .. as it's deployed on the SQL server ..

Comment: You need to understand that we can get the package path even if it is deployed in `SQL server` or `File System` .Check this artcile out http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2010/01/10/list-all-ssis-packages-deployed-on-your-integration-server/

Comment: The above article explains a sql code by which you can retrieve the package location deployed in MSDB (sql server )and it evens gives the entire package information in `xml`.Just run this sql code in C# get the package location and then perform the tasks.Lastly if SSIS package is deployed in SQL server then it is really easy to retrieve the `package path` ,`package config files` ,`package data` etc.Since all these informations are stored in either `msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders` or `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages ` tables

Comment: thank you so much .. i'm so sorry again for the many questions but really thank you :)

Comment: after I create and run the SP .. the packageData returned but encrypted as like
<EncryptedData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" Salt="Gnk/DB61AQ==" IV="iYcfV0NOGy0=">
  <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
  <CipherData>
    <CipherValue>/TtgJ46P9L23ZeGt67n+2OZGXoHiGWcUAWE8CdN1Z2aiF40fAg6DfBWGx62RB7Botxrw+f1Jf1CtR10iMLw0iz+VIcbaPFZj5ZfCm3aDeDLbnwXdb7mIdzNtF/5EOjNph/kPz7PxcUlAOUvsLLmjGtx92EhWL6KpXufKahnRiwLuZLNc</CipherValue>
  </CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
is there any easy way for decryption

Comment: This clearly means that your package is encrypted .U need to have a key to decrypt it and only the developer who created the package might help u with decrypting it

Comment: I got the key not but i dont know how to decrypt it ?

Comment: I have no idea about decrypting the package using T-sql .Try this link out `http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/33609/how-to-read-ssis-packagedata-field-contents-decryp.html` . else post it as new question may be some 1 can help you out

Answer (score 2):

The default package location if you deploy to file system is :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Packages (SQL 2008) or C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Packages (SQL 2005).

If you deploy to sql server, it's stored in the msdb database, so you can access it from SQL Server Management Studio.

1. Select 'Integration Services' in the connection option instead of 'Database Engine'.
2. Expand Stored Packages - Expand MSDB and search for your package (With the same name which you used during saving the package.)

Comment: yes in sql server,so it's stored in the msdb database but how could I retrieve it or open it ?

Comment: ok thank you for this but i want to get more details about the package.. is there anyway i could got deep in those packages . I mean in the .DTSX file there are the connection strings as example could i got this information ?

Comment: You will have to open the package in Visual Studio. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can import it through Visual Studio (or Business Intelligence Development Studio). Create a new SSIS project, right-click on packages, choose import and connect to the SQL Server that the package is stored on.